# Automation / Web Scraping - Header dynamic form codes

Tags: python, http, beautifulsoup, python-requests

Was hoping someone could help me here.  I am new to python, requests, beautiful soup. I am developing a script to help login to a website, search, add to cart, and check out.  I am running into specific issues with the login and add to cart function. When I inspect the website there seems specific token / code that gets passed along with the login credentials that periodically changes.  The same goes for the products and each product has a unique code that gets passed along with the add to cart data function.

I tried to hard code these values in the payload and pass them along. It will temporarily work - but does not work long term once the values change on the server side.... Any advice?

Comment: I think your only solution is to work for the site you are trying to automate, the token you use is probably temporary (it expires for example in 2 hours and can no longer be used).

Comment: Is the token / code not present on the home page? Try scraping that page just to get the code.